# SPO throwing invalid URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-form, hyperlink

I have a hyperlink field in my list. I use it for emails.
In Edge it throws an '`invalid url`' for any mail address, preceded with `mailto` or not. In Firefox I can set/change the emails.

There's no validation, no column formatting, just a basic list. We do use VALO intranet but this is mostly a presentation layer over sharepoint.

I can enter `http://` addresses just fine.

On a test tenant I don't have this issue; so it rather seems some kind of setting?

[image: invalid url]

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this issue on my tenant. I can set the mailto link from edge/chrome/firefox without any error. Also, there is no column/list level settings for this. Can you try creating a new list & new hyperlink column on same site & see if you face the same issue?

Comment: it's related to the list being synced; there's a sync icon in the list with the issue